# Final position visible during SharedElementTransition using RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, shared-element-transition

I'm using a `SharedElementTransition` when opening a new Activity. The shared element is in a `RecyclerView` in ActivityA (starting Activity), and also in a `RecyclerView` in a Fragment in ActivityB (new Activity). The animation works mostly as expected, except that the shared element is also visible in its final position throughout the animation, which looks pretty terrible.

My `ActivityB.onCreate()` looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    <snip>

    if (Utils.hasLollipop()) {
        postponeEnterTransition();
    }
}
```

In the `ViewHolder.onBindViewHolder()` for the holder that contains the image I'm using as a shared element, I call this after loading the image data into the view (in a Picasso callback):

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void triggerTransition() {
    if (!hasTriggeredTransition) {
        hasTriggeredTransition = true;
        sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                sharedElement.setTransitionName("sharedElement");
                sharedElement.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                containingFragment.getActivity().startPostponedEnterTransition();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The image transitions from its location in ActivityA to where it should be in ActivityB, but during the animation, it also appears in the final location. How can I hide the final location until the animation is finished?

**Update:** In an attempt at simplifying, I've removed the image callbacks. Now, I just set the view to a solid background color and immediately calling `triggerTransition()`, with the same results.

Relatedly, is there a way to slow down the animation for debugging?

Comment: I've discovered that I can get the correct results by removing the content from the RecyclerView during the animation and instead showing it above the RV in a LinearLayout. However, it would be really nice if I didn't have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to slow down the animation for debugging purposes by increasing the duration value in your transition xml file like below:

```
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:transitionOrdering="together"

    android:duration="250">
```

You can even change the Ordering to "sequencing" to further analyse..